# Make 2 cardlet Java Card communicate

Tags: applet, smartcard, channel, javacard

I have 2 cardlets Java Card **on the same smart card** that I want to make communicate.

I could select an applet then send the corresponding APDU and then deselect it and select the other one and etc... I am wondering if it is possible to do it 
*more properly*
 with logical channels ? I mean with a method that could allow me to not select/deselect each applet for each APDU command ?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

You need a card that supports additional logical channels.In that case, you can select more than one applet simultaneously.(One applet per each channel) Fortunately current cards support some additional logical channels.

But remember that if you want to select (at least) two applets of a single package simultaneously, you must implement `MultiSelectable` interface in both applets (and also in all the other applets of that package).

If your applets are not from a single package, you don't need to implement this interface.

After that, you can open 2 logical channel using *MANAGE CHANNELS* command and select *App1* in channel 0, and *App2* in channel 1 (For example). For the next commands, you specify which channel (and therefore which applet) is the target of the incoming command using the low nibble in the `CLA` section of that APDU commands.

Note that *SELECT APDU* command is an alternative for *MANAGE CHANNELS-Open* command.(So you actually don't even need to use *MANAGE CHANNELS* command)

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You should read more about: Applet Firewall, Sharable Objects and Inter-Applet Communication. These are standard Javacard features that are (also but not only) designed for this purpose.

Comment: I think the questioner asked something else in the question! He don't want to share something between applets, he want to select two applet simultaneously. No?

Comment: "I have 2 cardlets Java Card on the same smart card that I want to make **communicate**" Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: But the three next line? :) So I think he asked two question here!

Comment: no idea. "I could" sounds like a helpless solution approach to me. Doesn't matter though, he got both answers now